# Get row and column in Pandas for a cell with a certain value

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read an Excel spreadsheet that is unformatted using Pandas.  There are multiple tables within a single sheet and I want to convert these tables into dataframes.  Since it is not already "indexed" in the traditional way, there are no meaningful column or row indices.  Is there a way to search for a specific value and get the row, column where that is?  For example, say I want to get a row, column number for all cells that contain the string "Title".

I have already tried things like DataFrame.filter but that only works if there are row and column indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do some long and hard to read list comprehension:

```
# assume this df and that we are looking for 'abc'
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['abc', 'def','wert','abc'], 'col2':['asdf', 'abc', 'sdfg', 'def']})

[(df[col][df[col].eq('abc')].index[i], df.columns.get_loc(col)) for col in df.columns for i in range(len(df[col][df[col].eq('abc')].index))]
```

out:

```
[(0, 0), (3, 0), (1, 1)]
```

I should note that this is (index value, column location)

you can also change `.eq()` to `str.contains()` if you are looking for any strings that contains a certain value:

```
[(df[col][df[col].str.contains('ab')].index[i], df.columns.get_loc(col)) for col in df.columns for i in range(len(df[col][df[col].str.contains('ab')].index))]
```

Answer (score 13):

Create a df with NaN where your_value is not found.
Drop all rows that don't contain the value.
Drop all columns that don't contain the value

```py
    a = df.where(df=='your_value').dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1)
```

To get the row(s)

```py
    a.index
```

To get the column(s)

```py
    a.columns
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a mask of the same shape than your df by calling `df == 'title'`.
You can then combines this with the `df.where()` method, which will set all fields to NA that are different to your keyword, and finally you can use `dropna()` to reduce it to all valid fields. Then you can use the `df.columnns`and `df.index`like you're use to.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0,1,2], "b": [0, 9, 7]})
print(df.where(df == 0).dropna().index)
print(df.where(df == 0).dropna().columns)

#Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
#Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to fetch all the row and column index of the cells containing word 'title' -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['here goes the title', 'tt', 'we have title here'],
                  'B': ['ty', 'title', 'complex']})
df


+---+---------------------+---------+
|   |          A          |    B    |
+---+---------------------+---------+
| 0 | here goes the title | ty      |
| 1 | tt                  | title   |
| 2 | we have title here  | complex |
+---+---------------------+---------+


idx = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('title'))

col_idx = []
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    col_idx.append(df.iloc[:,i][idx.iloc[:,i]].index.tolist())


out = []
cnt = 0
for i in col_idx:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        out.append((i[j], cnt))
    cnt += 1
out

# [(0, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1)]   # Expected output
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @firefly works if the second dropna gets the how='all', too like so:

```
a = df.where(targetMap == 'your_value').dropna(how='all').dropna(how='all',axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that's in the vein of @It_is_Chris's solution, but may be a little easier to read:

```
# assuming this df and that we are looking for 'abc'
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['abc', 'def','wert','abc'], 'col2':['asdf', 'abc', 'sdfg', 'def']})
[x[1:] for x in ((v, i, j) for i, row_tup in enumerate(df.itertuples(index=False)) for j, v in enumerate(row_tup)) if x[0] == "abc"]
```

#### Output

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (3, 0)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Similar to what Chris said, I found this to work for me, although it's not the prettiest or shortest way.  This returns all the row,column pairs matching a regular expression in a dataframe:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    col_count = 0
    for col in row:
        if regex.match(str(col)):
            tuples.append((row_count, col_count))
            col_count+=1
        row_count+=1

return tuples
```